# Specify that model binder must use specific value provider for a property

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

This is more of a curiosity for me than something I actually need to do. Is there a way to tell the model binder that it should only attempt to find a value using a specific IValueProvider?

ie: Let's say I have a model whose Id property I want to be bound specifically from the QueryStringValueProvider. The way the default value provider works is a first-with-value-wins situation. So if I have a value provider registered before the QueryStringValueProvider, and that provider returns a value first, then the query string value is ignored entirely.

I know I can make a custom ModelBinder and deal with it that way, but I'm wondering if there's a built in way of handling this already(like popping an attribute on the property or something)?